# Airflow catchup new tasks added to dag

Tags: airflow

When you deploy a new DAG with `catchup=True` Airflow scheduler automatically schedules all the tasks from the `start_date` till now. It finishes and you get a lot of dark green balls meaning those DAGs in the past have been run.

But now you want to add new tasks to the past DAG runs. What should I do to make the old DAG runs recognize the new tasks and run them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to airflow cli, you can use the [backfill command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/cli-ref.html#backfill) to run the new task for any period of time. The command does not re-run any of the tasks that have already run in subsequent dag runs.

Start and end dates to backfill are optional, so you could just run

`$ airflow backfill your_dag_id`

Comment: I have since this question learned about the backfill, and the regex option is fantastic for this use cases

Answer (score 3):

You should [clear](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#clear) the old DAG runs (can also be done in the GUI). The cleared runs will be rescheduled including the newly added tasks.

Comment: additionally to avoid wasteful computation of tasks that need not be rerun for past dates, one can write a custom script to first clear old DagRuns and then create false entries for already computed tasks; that ways only the newly added tasks would be run

Comment: I don't want to loose the logs and run information about the already run 2000 tasks. I understand that when the DAG is finished there's no point on adding tasks, it's cheating in the contract. I'll try setting the old DAGs to "running" and see if it does the trick. I suppose the scheduler should reevaluate the dag deps

Comment: @dinigo You will not lose the old logs, the new runs will produce new logs. You can find the run info in the logs too.

Comment: I wasn't able to clear the logs. I suspect the Airflow version I was using did not create the task instances propperly. Because in local development environment airflow lets me catch up by removing but in prod it does not. So it is a DB thing now :/